# Execute KNN approximate search using OpenSearch Java client

Tags: java, cosine-similarity, amazon-opensearch

I am trying to execute KNN approximate search using the OpenSearch Java client.
I cant find any example nor documentation about it (both high-level and low-level clients).

I am able to execute the command from the OpenSearch dashboard.
For example:

```
GET contentml-images-clip-batch1/_search
{
  "size": 2,
  "query": {
    "knn": {
      "embedding": {
        "vector": [1,2,3],
        "k": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any good reference for how to achieve the sam call using one of the Java clients?